# Angular 2 - Prevent Change Detection

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I have a `setInterval()` function in a component class that fires off every 1/10 of a second. All it does is update a d3 graph and does not touch any angular bindings.

By default `setInterval()` triggers the change detection in angular from the root node.

Is there a way to run the `setInterval()` function without triggering any change detection?

I don't need the rest of the app to update itself since I know this only affects the graph and d3 is the only one responsible for the updating the graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to run it outside of angular. Take a look at this answer to a similar question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39626378/1710501