# Angular 2 - how to Prevent Change Detection

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

**i want to avoid change detection, i tried one method but i want to use outside of angular concept**

[plunkr sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/6Ea2PFW9a186TBQxES1r?p=preview)
*this link has my plunkr sample , i tried one method to avoid change detection which creating micro task *

```js
onClick() {
    this.num++;
    
    this.cdRef.detach();
    this.ngZone.onMicrotaskEmpty.first().subscribe(() => {
      this.cdRef.reattach();
    });
  }
```

**i refered this question but i could not find my sollution**
[relative question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995262/how-to-disable-angular2-change-detection-for-3rd-party-libraries/39626378#39626378)

Comment: Why do you need to prevent change detection?

Comment: in my project performance lack issue occurred so  my frd suggest me to avoid change detection

Comment: You can set your component change detection to `OnPush` in component metadata. Have you tried that?

Comment: can you please see this plunkr. https://plnkr.co/edit/6Ea2PFW9a186TBQxES1r?p=preview

Comment: i simply created micro-task to avoid change detection ,it worked fine

Comment: Then what is your question? Also, It's not about `higher authority told me to do so`, it's `why do we need it? Can we achieve better performance in a better way`. Show me some of your code, and explain where the performance issue occurs.

Comment: okay wait, i will show where performance issue occur

Comment: Do not send the whole project. Just show your component and problematic part. Also, if you want to share your entire project, can you provide a github repo?

Comment: i am not gonna share my entire project. i will send my sample only.....

Comment: did you see this -> https://plnkr.co/edit/6Ea2PFW9a186TBQxES1r?p=preview

Comment: Yes, I already clicked on that link when you put it in your question but it does not mean anything to me. I still don't know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: in that plunkr, i used "    this.ngZone.onMicrotaskEmpty.first().subscribe(() => {
" this methid to avoid change detection

Comment: but i want use like this "this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
".....for reference see this question==>  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995262/how-to-disable-angular2-change-detection-for-3rd-party-libraries/39626378#39626378

Comment: Then, just use it. What's the problem?

Comment: i dint know how to that method, that is problem so only i created this question bro?

Comment: can you please say how to inject that concept into my plunkr project instead of  this  "this.ngZone.onMicrotaskEmpty.first().subscribe"

Comment: Okay, there is a communication problem between us. You said that you found an example and tried to use it within your code without even sharing your own code. I still haven't seen your code or understood your problem. If you want to use `ngZone.runOutsideAngular`, just use it. I cannot tell you how to implement it within your code without even seeing it. Please, if you don't share any more information, I won't even try to help you.

Comment: okay, that plunkr is my sample  bro, i have to create sample with "ngZone.runOutsideAngular" method so i created that sample. there i dont know how to use "ngZone.runOutsideAngular"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 runOutsideAngular still change the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40300635/angular-2-runoutsideangular-still-change-the-ui)

Comment: okay bro thanks a lot, again we have communication problem

Comment: i already saw that question but there they dint give solution to "how to use runoutsideAngular method"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 onClick() {
    debugger
    this._ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      // this.num++
      setTimeout(()=>this.num = 5);    
      });
  }
```

**i used this code  instead of using microtask method, it works fine**