# mousemove triggers change detection continuously in Angular

Tags: angular

I've noticed mousemove on certain element triggers change detection continuously. I've researched this issue and discovered they suggest to use `runOutsideAngular` method of `NgZone`.

So I tried like,

```
this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
  this.element.addEventListener('mousemove', {});
});
```

which didn't work at all.

Did I misuse `runOutsideAngular` or is there any other workaround to prevent the endless change detection on mousemove event? Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

@EDIT
For the comment question: `the canvas element rendered by a third party library`

[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995262/how-to-disable-angular2-change-detection-for-3rd-party-libraries)

For general purpose:

You need to use a `renderer: Renderer2` listener.

Please read this [Article](https://medium.com/javascript-everyday/adding-event-listeners-outside-of-the-angular-zone-a22f9cfc80eb)

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, NgZone, Renderer2, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mouse-tracker',
  templateUrl: './mouse-tracker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mouse-tracker.component.css']
})
export class MouseTrackerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('area', { static: true }) area: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;
  private unlisten: Function;

  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      this.unlisten = this.renderer.listen(
        this.area.nativeElement,
        'mousemove',
        () => this.drawLine()
      );
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unlisten();
  }

  drawLine() {
    console.log('Drawing a line which does not require bindings update...');
  }

  getLabel(): string {
    console.log('Label is being computed...');

    return 'exemplary label';
  }
}
```

and template:

```
<p>mouse-tracker works!</p>
<p>{{ getLabel() }}</p>

<div #area></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works in a separate, pure element but the thing is that the one which triggers the change detection in my case is a canvas which is created by a library I'm using so I've tried your answer with: `this.renderer.listen(this.el.nativeElement // the container element which contains the canvas element, 'mousemove', () => {})` but it didn't work :( any idea?

Comment: `'mousemove', () => {}` is runOutsideAngular, in our example : this.drawLine() is the function that run oustise angular

Comment: I don't want to execute anything on `mousemove` event. The problem is that the change detection is triggered on every single mousemove on the container element which contains the canvas element rendered by a third party library so I was wondering if I could prevent to hear `mousemove` event or make Angular not detect the `mousemove` event by using runOutsideAngular method.

Comment: @DongBinKim `the canvas element rendered by a third party library ` , it must be a third party function, like: myCanvasObject.draw(), and then, this function will run outside.

Comment: Actually, nothing is supposed to happen upon mousemove event. It just keeps triggering the change detection on mousemove and that is the problem.

Comment: @DongBinKim have you managed to find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when the user was dragging dialog windows.

The solution was to inject `ChangeDetectorRef` and call `detach()` `onMouseDown` and `reattach()` `onMouseUp`